# Launching Facebook from my app -- blank page

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, facebook

I have a question regarding launching Facebook on a iPhone/iPod/iPad device. I built an application where you have a button that launches the official Facebook application (if the user doesn't have the Facebook application, it will launch it in Safari instead). So this is the code I used to launch Facebook:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://106452802751829"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But the problem is that it's showing a blank page in the Facebook application. I revised the code again, checked twice on my Facebook fan page's ID, but I get nothing but a blank page. So now I don't know what to do. I hope someone can help me out here with launching the actual fan page on the official Facebook application; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this Wiki [iPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)

This information comes from the iPhoneDevTools website.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"]; 
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

> You can use these options: fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the
>   user’s profile fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
>   fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list
>   (NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page
>   opens.
>
> However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the
>   Facebook app) fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
>   fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page fb://requests –
>   Open Facebook app to the Requests list fb://notes- Open Facebook app
>   to the Notes page fb://albums – - Open Facebook app to Photo Albums
>   list This "works" but, then again, doesn't: fb://post/ It
>   only works if the Facebook app has previously loaded the particular
>   post, otherwise it draws a blank.